# Jquery get xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to download a XML file via a jquery .get() request. unfortunately the returned data seems to be empty (0 length string), even if the browser downloads correctly the XML file (the request returns a 200 http code via firebug)

here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    Test sportevai<br/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://risultati.sportevai.it/sportevai_widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.get('http://servername.com/xml/10225.xml', function(data) {
            alert(data.length);
        $('.xcf').html(data);

        });

        });
</script>
<div id="xcf">div response</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get XML from a **remote** domain like this, you can only fetch JSONP.  The [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents it.  What will happen is exactly what you're experiencing, everything will appear normal except that the response will be empty.

You'll have to proxy the request through your domain/site or go a different route altogether, if you have to use XML.  If you can fetch [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), you can do this strictly in JavaScript.